# Error: Main method not found in class myPackage.inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

```
package myPackage;

public class inheritance {
     int salary = 50000;
}

class worker extends inheritance {
    int bonus = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        worker obj1 = new worker();
        System.out.println("employee salary is" + obj1.salary);
        System.out.println("employee bonus is" + obj1.bonus);
    }
}
```

Hi.. I am new to java. I am trying to write an inheritance program and getting this error.

> Error: Main method not found in class myPackage.inheritance, please define the main method as:
>       public static void main(String[] args)
>       or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Error is right. `worker`  has `main`, `inheritance` don't have `main`. Run worker instead of inheritance.

Comment: TAsk has identified the problem - but please format the code in your post and in future posts; it's *really* hard to read at the moment.

Comment: Also the ' symbol at the end may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the main method inside of `inheritance` class like this:

```
public class inheritance {
    int salary = 50000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        worker obj1 = new worker();
        System.out.println("employee salary is" + obj1.salary);
        System.out.println("employee bonus is" + obj1.bonus);
    }
}

class worker extends inheritance {
    int bonus = 10000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This error can happen in multiple ways

First need to clarify how you are compiling and running your program

1.Ensure that the java files are placed in the correct package(folder) itself

2.Ensure location of your class file is added to your class path variable

Most probably your problem will be solved by making the inheritance class as public.

```
package myPackage;
class inheritance {
int salary = 50000;}
public  class worker extends inheritance {
int bonus = 10000;
public static void main(String[] args) {
worker obj1 = new worker();
System.out.println("employee salary is" + obj1.salary);
System.out.println("employee bonus is" + obj1.bonus);
}
}
```

Comment: @stephen can u just tell what is wrong with the answer?The error can happen in all the ways i spaecified

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with the `public` modifier or lack of it.  See the first comment for the real explanation.  (The OP seems to think that static methods are inherited ....)

Comment: I am telling the ways in which the same error can happen.Even with the absence of public modifier it can happen if you are running the same with an IDE,Please have a try and comment.

Comment: 1) That is an IDE bug then.  The Java specs do not requite the class to be `public`.  2) It is not the OP's problem.  Answers should answer the actual question, not provide hints to people who have a >>different<< problem.

Comment: Even it is an IDE bug it is the right way to answer as the person who asked the question is a beginner in java and the steps followed for running the program is not mentioned.The same error can caused by different reasons.